# How to evict pods in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I'm testing a trigger i set on my k8s cluster. What it does it that detects if a pod is evicted. So to test I ran

`kubectl drain <NODENAME> --ignore-daemonsets --force`

but the evicted pods are just automatically deleted instead of staying in cluster.
Can you guys help me on how can I evict a pod?
I'm using kind to test this locally on my computer.
Actually I want to read the evicted pod yaml after its evicted so that I can build that trigger.

Comment: You can exhaust the node resources, eg write to ephemeral storage from a container without a limit on ephemeral storage space. Pods will start getting evicted when the node disk fills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer the title question: "How to evict pods in kubernetes?" There are a number of additional ways to trigger pod eviction, but two easy ones:

#### API Based Eviction

There is an API you can use to [evict a pod manually](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#create-eviction-pod-v1-core). To use the API:

- via curl: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/api-eviction/
- with a tool: https://github.com/rajatjindal/kubectl-evict-pod

### Apply a NoExecute Taint

A [NoExecute taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#concepts) that your pod does not tolerate will cause it to be evicted.

```
kubectl taint nodes node1 key1=value1:NoExecute
```

Now, the text of your question asks a slightly different question: reading the pod resource *after* a successful eviction. At least in my environment and k8s version, as soon as a pod is evicted, it is deleted by the service account associated with the node it was running on.

In practice, many things can delete pods - including [garbage collectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/), so querying a pod after it has been terminated is fraught with potential race conditions.

Instead, I would recommend setting up a programmatic watch for pod events. `client-go` offers [the Informer pattern](https://medium.com/codex/explore-client-go-informer-patterns-4415bb5f1fbd) to accomplish this with a bit of boilerplate.

Create an informer for Pods, define an `UpdateFunc` for your event handler, and you will reliably receive pod state changes as they are processed by the API -- which you can then assess to determine if they were evicted.